# Apply Custom Option via Ajax to a product

Tags: magento

Has anyone had any success in Applying a custom option to the product object via Ajax.
 ie. A ajax request will get triggered when ever I select a custom option which changes the product price.

I have a ajax Block in the Product View page that depends on the Product Price. Since Magento Applies the Custom Options after the product is added to the cart , I am finding it difficult to render the ajax block with my updated product price.

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this module, its good ajax cart and it has exactly what you need and you can customize it easily 
https://github.com/hws47a/VF_AjaxCart

Comment: I checked it out. But , what I am trying to achieve is quite different. I do not want to add the product to the cart , but simply update the product object to apply the custom options.